# Warning : Use SwitchCompat from AppCompat or SwitchMaterial from Material library

Tags: android, android-appcompat, lint, material-components-android, android-switch

What is the difference between these 2 objects (`SwitchCompat` and `SwitchMaterial`)? I have tried them and visually they are identical.

By the way, why did they remove the `Switch` class? Do you know which UI element is supposed to replace it in the future?

Comment: `androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat` worked for me

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [**`SwitchMaterial`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Switch.md):

- is provided by the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android)
- extends the `SwitchCompat`
- uses `Widget.MaterialComponents.CompoundButton.Switch` as default style, using the [colors](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Color.md) defined in the `Theme.MaterialComponents` (like `colorSecondary`, `colorSurface` and `colorOnSurface`) and applying the [Elevation Overlays](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Dark.md#elevation-overlays) in dark mode.

The **`SwitchCompat`**:

- is provided by the [androidx appcompat library](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat)
- uses `Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.Switch` as default style

> By the way, why did they remove the Switch class?

The [**`Switch`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch) class is not removed. It is provided by the android framework like other widgets as `Button`,`TextView`.. and the appcompat and material components libraries provide an updated version of them (like `AppCompatButton`, `MaterialButton`...).

There is a different with these widgets.
Using an `AppCompat` theme there is the [**`AppCompatViewInflater`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatViewInflater) that automatically replaces all usages of core Android widgets inflated from layout files by the AppCompat extensions of those widgets (for example a `Button` is replaced by `AppCompatButton`).
Using the `Theme.MaterialComponents`  there is the [**`MaterialComponentsViewInflater`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/theme/MaterialComponentsViewInflater) that replaces some framework widgets with Material Components ones at inflation time, provided a Material Components theme is in use (for example a `Button` is replaced by `MaterialButton`).

It is **NOT true** for the `SwitchMaterial` and the `SwitchCompat`.The reason for that is due to the AppCompat `SwitchCompat` not actually extending from the framework `Switch` class.

Comment: Yes, but WHY did they make this change? Why can't we just keep using Switch the same way we always have? What does the SwitchMaterial and SwitchCompat do that makes it worth converting?

Answer (score 14):

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/SwitchCompat

Switch have a different look for older versions of Android. we use SwitchCompat to have consistent look for all Android versions.

[image]

> SwitchCompat is a complete backport of the core Switch widget that
> brings the visuals and the functionality of that widget to older
> versions of the platform. Unlike other widgets in this package,
> SwitchCompat is not automatically used in layouts that use the
>  element. Instead, you need to explicitly use
> <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat> and the matching attributes
> in your layouts.

SwitchMaterial is inherited from SwitchCompat. it is a class that creates a Material Themed Switch.

Answer (score 5):

The switch view operates differently depending on which version of Android you are using. This might cause an issue if your app is being run in older versions or newer versions. To solve this, instead we can use `SwitchCompat` which operates the same on all versions currently.

To adjust this, go to xml code, instead of switch

```
// change from "Switch"
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/main_activity_sw_simulate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/coda"
        android:text="@string/switch_text"
        android:textColor="@color/onyx"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />
```

Comment: Is there anyway to provide description, summary to `SwitchCompat` in a similar way as it is possible to provide one using: `SwitchPreferenceCompat`, by using the e.g. `app:summaryOff` attribute?

Answer (score 2):

**SwitchCompat**

[SwitchCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/SwitchCompat) is an extended version of `CompoundButton`. `SwitchCompat` is a version of the old `Switch` widget which on devices back to `API v7`. It does not make any attempt to use the platform provided widget on those devices which it is available normally.

**SwitchMaterial**

It's an extended version of `SwitchCompat`. It creates a `Material Themed Switch`. This class uses attributes from the Material Theme to style a `Switch`.Because `SwitchCompat` does not extend `Switch`, you must explicitly declare [SwitchMaterial](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/switchmaterial/SwitchMaterial) in your layout XML.